# Looping through objects in Twig/Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

If I get an array of types using Doctrine like this:

```
$types = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('Model:Type')
    ->findAll();
```

And then pass $types to the Twig template (as 'types') and loop through it:

```
{% for type in types %}
-- WHAT GOES HERE?
{% endfor %}
```

I've been doing a bit of reading, and I'm not even sure if this is possible? Can I only pass associative arrays through to Twig or do arrays of objects work? And if so, how can I access the public functions  of the object in Twig?

Basically I want to call getName(), getUsage(), getId() and a few other public functions on the Type object.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you could do it like below:

```
{% for type in types %}
  {{ type.name }}
  {{ type.usage }}
  {{ type.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ type.getName() }}` also works, it's same with `{{ type.name }}`.